# Passing Underscore To a Type Constructor

Tags: scala, types, existential-type

I came across a method today which has a signature as follows:

```
def foo() : Future[_] = { /* some code */ }
```

My question is what does the return type mean here? Does it mean that this method returns a `Future` and I do not care what the type of the computation is? Or is it something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Future[_]`-type is just [the placeholder syntax for existential type](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/03-types.html#existential-types):

```
Future[X] forSome { type X }
```

so that

```
def foo(): (Future[X] forSome { type X }) = { /* some code */ }
```

means: `foo` returns a `Future` with a value of some unknown type `X`. So, your interpretation

> "this method returns a Future and I do not care what the type of the computation is"

is correct.